# Understanding of minbucket function in CART model using R

Tags: r

Assume the training data is `fruit`, which I am going to use for prediction in a CART model in R:

```
fruit = data.frame(color=c("red", "red", "red", "yellow", "yellow",
                           "orange", "green", "pink", "red", "red"),
                   isApple=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
                             FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
mod = rpart(isApple ~ color, data=fruit, method="class", minbucket=1)
prp(mod)
```

Could anyone explain what is exactly the role of `minbucket` in plotting CART tree for this example if we are going to use `minbucket = 2, 3, 4, 5`?

Say `fruit` is my data frame, I'm finding whether the outcome is apple or not? I have 5 red apples (4 TRUE, 1 FALSE), one FALSE value is tomato here, so what ever is red need not be an apple. But if I give `minbucket`=5 or 4 here, there is no split at all. Only for `minbucket` 1 to 3 there is a split beyond 3 there is no split. But I have more than 3 observation in my leaf node.

Comment: what package does `rpart` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation:

```
minbucket: the minimum number of observations in any terminal ‘<leaf>’
          node.  If only one of ‘minbucket’ or ‘minsplit’ is specified,
          the code either sets ‘minsplit’ to ‘minbucket*3’ or
          ‘minbucket’ to ‘minsplit/3’, as appropriate.
```

So if you set `minbucket` to 4, then `minsplit` is 12, and you've only got 10 observations so it refuses to split. Because:

```
minsplit: the minimum number of observations that must exist in a node
          in order for a split to be attempted.
```

Its all there in the documentation.